# Hackzall vs oscillating multi-tool

Tags: tools

If comparing the two, doesn't any oscillating multi-tool do the same or more than the Milwaukee Hackzall or similar products?

Comment: The tools are intended for very different kinds of jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a much, much slower way, with more dust and noise and shorter depth of cut, yes.

Your multitool will also not work well on steel.